# How to deactivate Order function in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am now building my own website that will show some pictures to users.
That's like ebay but unable to buy any items.
Just click and contact to the seller.
Here are 2 screenshots.

1. [image: List item]

For example, click the first item, then the second page will show up.

[image]

Like the screenshot, I do Not want to see the 'Add to cart'. Instead of that, I want to see this, Contact the seller then it will show the seller's phone number.

- I installed woocommerece & WV vendors plugins.
  If you have any good suggestion, It will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Woocommerece is for selling items. If you are trying to create a lookalike shop site, I'd recommend:

1. Creating a custom post type for the products
2. Create custom fields for all the properties of your product & seller information.
3. Style the page as you wish.

Woocommerece is totally not necessery here.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion :)

Comment: Is it possible that products' sellers register my website and then they can post theirs on my website? It still only shares their products' information. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: yes, you need to read about roles in wordpress, than give them permission to post items / (whatever they are called in the site) through the admin system. another approach is to user wp_create_post() and assign a form to the process so they would fill it and add the post. have fun!

Comment: glad to help, have a great day